# Retrieving look up lists in a layered application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, dependency-injection

I am playing around with an MVC 5 application and I have split the solution into the following layers:

DomainLayer - contains the POCO classes for my models along with all of my interfaces and services.
DataLayer - references Entity Framework and the DomainLayer, defines the DbContext and contains my repositories.
WebLayer - references the DomainLayer and DataLayer, makes calls to the services and renders the views.  I am using Unity to inject the required services into the controllers.

A number of my pages display drop down lists such as Manufacturer and Series, these look up lists are the same throughout the site and I would like a central way to fetch the data.

My initial thought was to create a LookUpListService, inject the repositories into it and have my other services call that.  This works however the more look up lists I have the more repositories I need to inject into the LookUpListService constructor.

I am now thinking that perhaps I should create an abstract factory and have my DataLayer implement it as this would automatically have access to all of the repositories and I would not need to inject them each time a new list came along.

Is there a better way of achieving this?  If not which of the above would be the better option?

Comment: Just use DbContext directly from LookUpListService and get rid of all that repositories. http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Comment: The LookUpListService is in the DomainLayer and does not have direct access to the context which is in the DataLayer.  Thats why I was thinking of putting the abstract factory in the DataLayer?

Comment: You can use some dependency injection framework like unity or something similar http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `LookUpListService` generic and accept generic repository (or if you have any, lookup repository).

```
public class LookUpListService<T> where T: IRepository{
    public LookUpListService(T repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    T repository;
    // your retrieval logic here
}
```

This way you can prevent huge constructor injection or class bloat from many lookup services.